# assembly code to scroll the screen one line down clearing the first line in the screen and then scrolls one line up if a key is pressed

Tags: windows, assembly, dos, masm, dosbox

I'm trying to scroll 1 line down then up but 
a) I don't know how to test this code 
b) I'm not sure which interrupt to use for "when a key is pressed"

I'd be much grateful for your help
Here's my code :

```
Data_segment_name  segment  para 

firstline db 160 dup(0)




Data_segment_name ends


Stack_segment_name segment para stack



Stack_segment_name ends


Code_segment_name segment 

Main_prog  proc far

    assume SS:Stack_segment_name,CS:Code_segment_name,DS:Data_segment_name

    mov AX,Data_segment_name         ; load the starting address of the data
    mov DS,AX                        ; segment into DS reg. 

    ;code scroll down (clear first line) then scroll back up(restore cleared line)

    mov es,ax                        ;save first line
    lea di,firstline
    mov ax,0b800h
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov si,ax                        
    cld
    mov cx,80
    rep movsw                        ;save ends

    ;now let's scroll down :)

    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov di,ax
    mov ax,160
    mov si,ax
    cld
    mov cx,24*80
    rep movsw

    ;now let's scroll up :)

    int 21h  ;check

    mov ax,160*24
    mov si,ax
    mov ax,160*25
    mov di,ax
    std
    mov cx,24*80
    rep movsw

    ;restore first line

    mov AX,Data_segment_name         ; load the starting address of the data
    mov DS,AX                        ; segment into DS reg. 
    lea si,firstline
    mov ax,0
    mov di,ax
    cld
    mov cx,80
    rep movsw


    mov ax,4c00h                     ; exit program
    int 21h


Main_prog      endp

Code_segment_name   ends
                end Main_prog
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad a):

The test tool is called "debugger". I recommend Turbo Debugger (google for it).

Ad b):

[Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm) and [TechHelp](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0002.HTM) are good references. At a glance: `Int 10h` is for video, `Int 16h` is for keyboard, `Int 21h` is for MS-DOS.

You should switch to the simplified segment directives `.CODE`, `.DATA`, `.STACK` and to procedural programming `PROC`, `ENDP`. When your project grows, it will help to keep track of it.

Example:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
    firstline db 160 dup(0)

.CODE
save_firstline PROC
    push ds
    mov ax, ds
    mov es, ax
    lea di, firstline
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, 0
    mov si, ax
    mov cx, 80
    rep movsw
    pop ds
    ret
save_firstline ENDP

restore_firstline PROC
    lea si, firstline
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0
    mov di, ax
    mov cx, 80
    rep movsw
    ret
restore_firstline ENDP

scroll_up PROC
    call save_firstline
    mov ah, 6               ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0096.htm
    mov al, 1               ; number of lines to scroll
    mov bh, 0               ; attribute
    mov ch, 0               ; row top
    mov cl, 0               ; col left
    mov dh, 25              ; row bottom
    mov dl, 80              ; col right
    int 10h
    ret
scroll_up ENDP

scroll_down PROC
    mov ah, 7               ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0097.htm
    mov al, 1               ; number of lines to scroll
    mov bh, 0               ; attribute
    mov ch, 0               ; row top
    mov cl, 0               ; col left
    mov dh, 25              ; row bottom
    mov dl, 80              ; col right
    int 10h
    call restore_firstline
    ret
scroll_down ENDP

main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    waitForKey:             ; http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0229.HTM
        mov   ah, 1
        int   16h
        jnz   gotKey        ; jmp if key is ready
        jmp   waitForKey    ; loop back and check for a key
    gotKey:
        mov ah, 0           ; key is ready, get it
        int 16h             ; now process the key

    cmp ah, 48h             ; <UP>
    jne @F
    call scroll_up
    jmp waitforKey

    @@:
    cmp ah, 50h             ; <DOWN>
    jne @F
    call scroll_down
    jmp waitForKey

    @@:
    cmp al, 1Bh             ; <ESC>
    jne waitForKey

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks for the suggested references but I don't think I understand what you did there?
"You should switch to the simplified segment directives .CODE, .DATA, .STACK and to procedural programming PROC, ENDP" 
Is this like writing functions for example in c++?
@rkhb

Comment: @Nemo: Yes. I checked the terms for Googleable accuracy ;-) - "Simplified segment directives" and "procedural programming" are two different things. With the former you let the assembler define the segments. The example program is complete. Copy it, assemble and link it. run it, debug it and learn as much as possible from it.

Comment: thanks a lot I read the code and understood most of it. Using interrupts for scrolling up and down is much easier. There's one problem though, I can't run the code. I get five severe errors. The @F and @@ are undefined. Are these supposed to be labels for a certain jump?

Comment: @Nemo: You tagged the question with <masm>. MASM understands @F and @@. @F means: "to the next @@" (F = forward). For a different assembler change the first `jne @F` to `jne J1`, the first `@@:` to `J1:`, the second `jne @F` to `jne J2` and the second `@@:` to `J2`.

Comment: I don't know then why it doesn't work. The application I'm running is named MASM @rkhb

Comment: @Nemo: My suggestions also work for MASM. I've discovered that version 5.0 doesn't understand @F and @@. If you use a version < 5.1 (more than 27 years old) you should mention it.

Comment: I didn't really know which version I was using. I'm learning assembly for a college course and the instructors install the versions to be used in the lab. I don't know why we're using such an old version but anyway thank you for pointing this out :D @rkhb

Comment: @Nemo: Do you now know which version you use? Shall I add a version of my program for your version of MASM or could you get it to work?

Comment: I don't know which version I'm using but I got it to work by modifying  my original code. I still want to divide my code into separate procs like you did.I'm working on it and would definitely appreciate the extra help :) @rkhb